# Unable to import LazyRegressor

Tags: python

I am unable to use LazyRegressor in my jupyter notebook.

After doing:

```
import lazypredict 
from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyRegressor
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/x1/m1tgn69x35zgjhktthtrg8cw0000gp/T/ipykernel_11270/2190481295.py in <module>
----> 1 from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyRegressor

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lazypredict/Supervised.py in <module>
     28 
     29 # import catboost
---> 30 import lightgbm
     31 
     32 warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/__init__.py in <module>
      6 from pathlib import Path
      7 
----> 8 from .basic import Booster, Dataset, Sequence, register_logger
      9 from .callback import early_stopping, log_evaluation, print_evaluation, record_evaluation, reset_parameter
     10 from .engine import CVBooster, cv, train

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py in <module>
    108 
    109 
--> 110 _LIB = _load_lib()
    111 
    112 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py in _load_lib()
     99     if len(lib_path) == 0:
    100         return None
--> 101     lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
    102     lib.LGBM_GetLastError.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
    103     callback = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_char_p)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py in LoadLibrary(self, name)
    458 
    459     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 460         return self._dlltype(name)
    461 
    462     __class_getitem__ = classmethod(_types.GenericAlias)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    380 
    381         if handle is None:
--> 382             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    383         else:
    384             self._handle = handle

OSError: dlopen(/Users/autobotraos/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: <8DF2AF67-B85F-3F67-B687-E50A514307EC> /Users/autobotraos/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

Is there a resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay found the answer. These files were missing.

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
conda install -c conda-forge lightgbm
```